# Jquery Datatable column search customization

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to customize the jquery data-table as per my requirement and I did some extend as well but its not solving my problem fully yet. Could anyone you please help me to accomplish the task what i'm trying to do.  My requirement is I have 3 columns (Name, Assignment group and Application name). According to assignment group selection value I have to populate application name that part completed and working as expected now. For One assignment group I may have more than one application names in such case the as per application name select the data-table body content should get update but actually its not happening.

```
For example : I'm selecting "Accountant" from assignment group drop-down, its populating tokyoN and tokyo  in application name drop-down and showing 2 records in data-table body content but when i try to select any one record from application name drop-down its not working. Please help me. its still show 2 records thanks in advance .

Here i attached the fiddle code with sample code which i have created. 

https://jsfiddle.net/sampleuser/wevq9z05/5/


Reference code: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html
from where I got the idea
```